# Live comments Update without realoading page in PHP posible?

Tags: php

i was viewing this [video](http://p2theme.com/) and i really want to develop this is PHP with no AJAX, do you how to start? where can i find some examples codes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live "streaming" without AJAX could be done in PHP using `ob_flush`/`flush`, ergo output buffering. But that's usually pretty dirty and unwanted. However, what you see in that video is only possible with Javascript/"AJAX" (or Flash and similar plugins).

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, i was viewing this video  and i
>   really want to develop this is PHP
>   with no AJAX, do you how to start?

There is no way to start as that functionality **requires** Ajax. Your hole is a square, why not use the square peg (Ajax).